# sql: How do I reserve one of the duplicated data with specific condition?

Tags: sql

there is a table and some record:

```
userno  | username
-------------------
1       |                         --this username is null value
1       | a
2       | b
2       |                         --this username is null value
3       | c
4       |                         --this username is null value
```

I want to **SELECT** this table, and I expect result is:

```
userno  | username
-------------------
1       | a
2       | b                 
3       | c
4       |
```

when `userno` is repetitive, reserve one data with `username` is **not null**;

when `userno` is not repetitive, reserve it.

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

**UPDATE1:**

there is a table and some record:

```
No  | field1  | flag
----------------------------
1   |         | 1             
1   | a       | 2
1   | b       | 3
1   | c       | 4
2   | c       | 1
2   | e       | 2
2   | f       | 5              
3   | c       | 0
4   |         |
```

I want to **SELECT** this table, and I expect result is:

```
No  | field1  | flag
-------------------
1   | a       | 2
2   | e       | 2                
3   | c       | 0
4   |         |
```

when `No` is repetitive, reserve one data with `flag=2`;

when `No` is not repetitive, reserver it.

Comment: Can a userno have several non-null usernames?

Comment: @jarlh yes. in fact, I want to specific any condition to reserve one data when userno duplicate.

Comment: Add the row (2, e), and adjust the expected result!

Comment: @jarlh I update my question, see **UPDATE1** section

Answer (score 6):

THIS ANSWERS THE ORIGINAL VERSION OF THE QUESTION.

You can use aggregation:

```
select userno, max(username) as username
from t
group by userno;
```

EDIT:

If you have multiple `username`s for a given `userno` and you want all of them:

```
select userno, username
from t
where username is not null
union all
select userno, max(username)
from t
group by userno
having max(username) is null;
```

Comment: Thank a lot! but if I want to reserve one of data with condithion(`username='b'`) when `userno` duplicated, how to do?

Comment: @Guo . . . It is rude to update a question after it has been answered.  That can invalidate existing answers, which draws downvotes.

Comment: sorry! what should I do when I need update question?